# perl - Net::SSLeay and Server Name Indications

Tags: perl, sni

Hello my friendly stackoverflow users,

I have the following code that "should" print out the cert for 'cyclingnews.com'

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                 
                                                                    
use strict;                                                         
use Net::SSLeay qw(get_https get_https3 make_headers);              
                                                                    
my $site = "cyclingnews.com";                                       
my ($p, $resp, $headers, $server_cert) = get_https3($site, 443, '/');                     
print "$headers\n";                                                 
my $PEM = Net::SSLeay::PEM_get_string_X509( $server_cert);          
print $PEM, "\n";
```

Upon inspection of the `.pem`, I see that the cert belongs to:

```
Subject: CN = *.ssl.hwcdn.net
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:*.ssl.hwcdn.net, DNS:ssl.hwcdn.net
```

So what I understand, this looks like a problem with `SNI` where `Net::SSLeay` is not passing a `SSL_hostname` to 'cyclingnews.com'. With `IO::SOCKETS::SSL` this can be done with `SSL_hostname` ( https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL#Basic-SSL-Client )

The `Net::SSLeay` doc ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay#Basic-set-of-functions ) says "By default `get_https()` supplies `Host` (to make virtual hosting easy) and `Accept` (reportedly needed by IIS) headers."

I am not sure if this relates to `get_https3()` so I have also tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                  
                                                                     
use strict;                                                          
use Net::SSLeay qw(get_https get_https3 make_headers);               
                                                                     
my $site = "cyclingnews.com";                                        
my ($p, $resp, $headers, $server_cert) = get_https3($site, 443, '/', 
              make_headers( 'Host:' => $site));                      
#);                                                                  
print "$headers\n";                                                  
my $PEM = Net::SSLeay::PEM_get_string_X509( $server_cert);           
print $PEM, "\n";
```

and this looks to pass the `Host` header but still same unwanted result.

so I am a bit lost, I'm a noob, so I know the folk on stackoverflow have a reputation for being freindly,  maybe y'all could give me some pointers

Comment: What output are you getting? How is it different from what you expect?

Comment: I get the `.pem` as expected but when I read with `openssl x509 -in test.pem -text` it is not the 'cyclingnews.com' certificate that I have verified in a web browser. I think it is the defaut website certificate of the webserver that hosts many virtual domains as it displays in  it's `Common Name` info.

Comment: @senorbrownie: Unfortunately what you want is simply not supported. The functionality is not in the code (specifically: no SNI support in `https_cat`). You are not doing anything wrong or miss anything. Use IO::Socket::SSL if you need easy access to SNI functionality.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich , thanks for that, now I know. if you can convert that to an answer, then I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_https3](https://github.com/radiator-software/p5-net-ssleay/blob/1.90/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm#L1441) like many similar functions ultimately ends up in [https_cat](https://github.com/radiator-software/p5-net-ssleay/blob/cc8647f408079485d845f3d7a19c244c134745be/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm#L1189) where the SSL context setup and the SSL handshake are done. Unfortunately, setting the `server_name` extension (SNI) is not done in this [really old part of the code](https://github.com/radiator-software/p5-net-ssleay/blame/cc8647f408079485d845f3d7a19c244c134745be/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm#L1189), which comes from a time where SNI wasn't that essentially for using HTTPS as it is today.