# Need a replacement for Net::SSLeay->get_https()

Tags: perl, ssl, sni

We have a high level Perl program which calls Net::SSLeay->get_https() with the correct high-level parameters such as host, path, port, and specific data fields. It's been working great. Until the target web site decided to require that the SNI be passed along as well.

Steffen Ullrich made a helpful comment here: [perl - Net::SSLeay and Server Name Indications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537126/perl-netssleay-and-server-name-indications)  So now we know that Net::SSLeay->get_https() cannot pass along the SNI.

I've looked at IO::Socket::SSL, Net::SSL, LWP and related routines, and all I see are low-level functions. What we really want is another high-level module we can call which will pass along the SNI. We can modify the parameters we pass this high-level module, so it doesn't have to be an exact replacement for Net::SSLeay->get_https(). But there's no way we have the expertise to get into the HTTPS details.

What Perl module(s) should we try?

Comment: Can't you use any HTTP library? Anything high-level enough should deal with SNI properly. `LWP::Curl` maybe?

Comment: *"I've looked at..., LWP ..."* - LWP is already very high level and there is LWP::Simple inside it which makes it even more high level. Not sure what you expect. SNI will be used automatically, no need to do it explicitly. If this is not sufficient please specify the exact requirements you have.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steffen for their comment. We found a way for our software to call LWP on the backend and it's working nicely.